# Why does a newly deployed Angular app not load components?

Tags: angular, nginx, digital-ocean

I have an Angular app with the following app.module.ts file content. I recently moved it to a DigitalOcean Droplet (Ubuntu 18) and after moving the dist folder components to the /var/www/html folder, it loads the homepage but none of the components.

The website is [this](http://kshitijsinha.com) and the links in the top nav don't work, they redirect to a 404 error page.

The components load perfectly fine on the local server (Mac). I even tried changing the route path to "app/..." but even that doesn't work.

File contents are below.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AboutmeComponent } from './aboutme/aboutme.component';
import { ProjectsComponent } from './projects/projects.component';
import { ResumeComponent } from './resume/resume.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';
import { AllComponent } from './projects/all/all.component';
import { ProjectholderComponent } from  './projects/projectholder/projectholder.component';
import { SkillsComponent } from './aboutme/skills/skills.component';
import { RiderappComponent } from './projects/mobileapps/riderapp/riderapp.component';
import { SpectrumComponent } from './projects/webapps/spectrum/spectrum.component';
import { NormansprinciplesComponent } from './projects/misc/normansprinciples/normansprinciples.component';
import { WebappsComponent } from './projects/webapps/webapps.component';
import { MobileappsComponent } from './projects/mobileapps/mobileapps.component';
import { IotComponent } from './projects/iot/iot.component';
import { MiscComponent } from './projects/misc/misc.component';
import { TouchstreamComponent } from './projects/webapps/touchstream/touchstream.component';
const routes: Routes = [
   {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
   { path: 'resume', component: ResumeComponent },
   { path: 'aboutme', component: AboutmeComponent },
   { path: 'projects', component: ProjectsComponent },
   { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
   { path: 'projects/all', component: AllComponent },
   { path: 'projects/webapps', component: WebappsComponent },
   { path: 'projects/webapps/touchstream', component: TouchstreamComponent 
},
{ path: 'projects/iot', component: IotComponent },
{ path: 'projects/misc', component: MiscComponent },
{ path: 'projects/mobileapps', component: MobileappsComponent },
{ path: 'projects/mobileapps/riderapp', component: RiderappComponent },
{ path: 'projects/webapps/spectrum', component: SpectrumComponent },
{ path: 'projects/misc/normansdesignprinciples', component: 
NormansprinciplesComponent }
];

 @NgModule({
   exports: [ RouterModule ],
   imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ]
 })
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: The link is giving `403` error. Please check it. And have you checked your `.htaccess` file? (Assuming you are using Apache)

Comment: Sorry about that. Yes, it's giving 404 error. And I'm using nginx.

Comment: So I Fixed the 403 error by reuploading the dost folder. But I still get the 404 errors on other components.

Comment: I found something like this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/nginx-404-error-with-existing-urls-angular-2-one-page-application-with-routing Maybe it can help.

Comment: That worked! Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help :)